# TypeError: Cannot set property 'state' of undefined in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, single-sign-on

I'm trying to do SSO login in my application. using `passport` & `passport-ci-oidc` `node modules`. getting below error. i've tried module version changing aswell still no luck.

[image]

while calling below API error is throwing,

```
router.get('/login', passport.authenticate('openidconnect', { state: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,10)}));
```

---passport.use() code ----

```
const strategy = require('./ssoconfig');
passport.use(strategy);
router.get('/login', passport.authenticate('openidconnect', { state: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,10)}));
```

Filename is ssocofig.js

`clientid`, `client_secret`, `callback_url` and `discovery_URL` details are coming from config file

```
const OpenIDConnectStrategy = require('passport-ci-oidc').IDaaSOIDCStrategy;
const config_setting = require("../config/config");

// console.log('Config Setting- Config', config_setting);

const strategy = new OpenIDConnectStrategy({

    clientID : config_setting.client_id,

    scope : 'email',

    response_type : 'email',
    
    clientSecret : config_setting.client_secret,

    callbackURL : config_setting.callback_url,

    skipUserProfile : true,

    discoveryURL: config_setting.discovery_URL,
    
    // issuer : settings.config.local.openidconnect.issuer_id

    }, function(iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, params, done) {
      console.log(profile);
      process.nextTick(function() {
        profile.accessToken = accessToken;
        profile.refreshToken = refreshToken;
        done(null, profile);
      })
    }
  );

module.exports = strategy;
```

---

help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you include the part of your code where you define your actual strategy, like `passport.use(new OpenIDConnectStrategy...`?

Comment: @FabianStrathaus `passport.use()` code is added